# What exactly is Standard Coordinates?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

What exactly is a standard coordinates?

Sorry it seems like a very stupid question, but my professor didn't really explain it and just started to use it for solving other problems related to transformation, so I got a little bit lost.

Does it mean the standard basis in $\mathbb{R}^n$?  For example, vector $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are the vectors form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$, does it mean $(1,0)\ ,\ (0,1)$ are the standard coordinates?

Could you please provide me an example of a standard coordinates?

Thank you very much!

Comment: To my knowledge "standard coordinates" is not a technical term. Your professor is probably alluding to representing vectors in $\mathbb R^2$ as pairs $(x,y)$.

Comment: There is a question about it : B(a,b) is a basis in R2, where a=(6,-5) b=(-7,4); Then, the matrix which converts from B coordinates to standard coordinates is ? (and it should be a 2x2 matrix)

Comment: "Standard" is being used as an ordinary English word here.

Answer (score 2):

Let $V$ be a vector space over field $F$. An object of the form $(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$ where the entries $a_i$ are elements from a field F is called an **n-tuple** with entries from $F$. Two n-tuples $(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$ and $(b_1,b_2,...,b_n)$ with entries form $F$ are called **equal** if $a_i=b_i$ for $i=1,2,...n$.

The set of all n-tuples with entries from F is a vector space, which we denote by $F^n$, under the operations of coordinatewise addition and scalar multiplication;  that is, if $u=(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)\in F^n$,  $v=(b_1,b_2,...,b_n)\in F^n$, and $c \in F$, then

\begin{equation}
u+v=(a_1+b_1,a_2+b_2,...,a_n+b_n)\quad \textrm{and} \quad cu=(ca_1,ca_2,...,ca_n)
\end{equation}

In $F^n$, let $e_1=(1,0,0,...,0), e_2=(0,1,0,...,0),...,e_n=(0,0,...,0,1)$, then $\{e_1,e_2,...,e_n\}$ is readily seen to be a basis for $F^n$ and is called the **standard basis** for $F^n$.

An **ordered basis** for $V$ is a basis for $V$ endowed with specific order; that is, an ordered basis for V is a finite sequence of linearly independent elements of $V$ that generates $V$. For the vector space $F^n$ we call $\{e_1,e_2,...,e_n\}$ the **standard ordered basis** for $F^n$.

**Standard coordinates** denotes coordinates with respect to the standard basis

Answer (score 1):

"Standard coordinates" typically denotes coordinates with respect to the standard basis.

Consider the following definition.

> If $\mathcal{A}=(a_1,...,a_n)$ and $\mathcal{B} = (b_1,...,b_n)$ are two bases of an $n$-dimensional
>   linear space $V$, then the *change of basis matrix* from $\mathcal{B}$
>   to $\mathcal{A}$ is a matrix $S_{\mathcal{B}\rightarrow \mathcal{A}}$
>   such that:
>
> $$[f]_{\mathcal{A}} = S[f]_{\mathcal{B}}, \forall f \in V$$

Note that:

$$S_{\mathcal{B}\rightarrow \mathcal{A}} = \left( \begin{array}{ccc} | &  & |\\ [b_1]_\mathcal{A} & ... & [b_n]_\mathcal{A}\\ | & & |\end{array} \right)$$

So coming back to your question (in the comments):
if $\mathcal{B} = \{\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
6 \\
-5 \end{array} \right),\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-7 \\
4 \end{array} \right)\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$, then a matrix that converts from $\mathcal{B}$ coordinates to standard coordinates $\mathcal{E} = \{\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 \\
0 \end{array} \right),\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 \\
1 \end{array} \right)\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is:

$$S_{\mathcal{B}\rightarrow \mathcal{E}} = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-\frac{4}{11}& -\frac{7}{11}\\
-\frac{5}{11}& -\frac{6}{11}\end{array} \right)$$

I'll leave it to you to verify this result.

Comment: So basically it question means to find the matrix that transform the other matrix to it's standard basis? By standard basis, does it mean the identity matrix for any matrix? If I reduce one 4x4 matrix to RREF, and only got two leading ones instead of 4, the standard matrix is (1,0) and (0,1)?  Thank you!