# matrix represented w.r.t. bases satisfying ker and im

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the elements $u_1=(1,3)^T$, $u_2=(0,1)^T$ of $^2\mathbb{R}$, and the elements $v_1=(1,2,5)^T$, $v_2=(2,3,0)^T$, $v_3=(0,1,1)^T$ of $^3\mathbb{R}$.

You may use without proof the facts that $B=${$u_1,u_2$} and $C=${$v_1,v_2,v_3$} are bases of $^2\mathbb{R}$ and $^3\mathbb{R}$ respectively. Let $B'=${$(1,0)^T,(0,1)^T$} and $C'=${$(1,0,0)^T,(0,1,0)^T,(0,0,1)^T$} be the standard bases of $^2\mathbb{R}$ and $^3\mathbb{R}$ respectively.

(i) Write down a $3$ x $2$ matrix $A$ such that the map $f:^2\mathbb{R}\rightarrow^3\mathbb{R}$ represented by $A$ with respect to $B$ and $C$ satisfies

ker($f$)= <$u_1$>, and im($f$)= <$v_1$>

(ii) Determine the transition matrix from $B$ to $B'$

I don't know how to do any of it because this function hasn't been given a rule to assign elements from the dom to the codom.

Comment: The rule is $f(x)=Ax$.

Comment: but I don't know what A is so it doesn't help...

Comment: Finding $A$ is exactly what you are being asked to do in (i). You are being asked to find a matrix $A$ such that the function given by $f(x)=Ax$ has kernel spanned by $u_1$ and image spanned by $v_1$.

Comment: i know but how would i do this? normally i would just do f(u_1)=a11*v_1+a21*v_2+a31*v_3 and compare this with the result of f(u_1) found by a general rule.

Comment: The image of $f$ is the column space of $A$, so you want each column of $A$ to be a multiple of $v_1$. Simplest to just let one of the columns be $v_1$, and then figure out what the other column has to be in order for $u_1$ to be in the kernel.

Comment: yeah I just got the 3x2 matrix {(0,1),(0,0),(0,0)} for A. What would A be wrt the standard bases B' and C'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matrix in part (i) of your question can be written as:

$$A = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -\frac{1}3 \\
2 & -\frac{2}3 \\
5 & -\frac{5}3 \end{array} \right]$$

Can you verify that the $\operatorname{im}A = \operatorname{span}\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 \\
2 \\
5\end{array} \right]$ and the $\ker A = \operatorname{span}\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 \\
3\end{array} \right]$?

I have given a definition for the transition, or *change of basis matrix*, in my answer to a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1042253/194721). I hope you will find it useful in answering part (ii) of your question.

Comment: how did you know that the matrix A is that?